# return bool as POST response using flask

Tags: python, api, flask, return, boolean

I'm mocking an Post api (written in C#) which return a bool value true or false when called.
The content-type is application/json for the request

```
true
```

I am now trying to mock that endpoint in Python using Flask and I'm struggling to make it pass a boolean value.

I tried

```
return make_response(True,200)
```

or simply

```
return True
```

and in both cases the api fails sending the desired response and throws errors.

In a desperate attempt I tried returning "True" as a string

```
return make_response("True", 200)
```

That seemed to work at the mock level, but the consuming code (c#) fails as it tries to convert that return value into bool by

```
result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result
```

Any ideas on how to make the mock api return a bool value ???

Comment: Does the c# bit still fail if you use a string with lower case t?

Comment: yes tried sending make_response("true",200)

Comment: So make.response() returns a flask.response object. Is that what you want in the next step past the return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should consider sending json data.

```
return json.dumps(True)
```

Comment: You can dump it as json and send it, I have tried it's working. 
As I know about standard json should be used for communication between REST client and REST server.

Comment: @DanielF  as Davidsm mentions I dont have any control over what data is returned but to mock. I agree it is a bad design to return a boolean as part of Json without any key.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning valid JSON.  In JSON the boolean is lowercase, `"true"`.  You can use `json.dumps` to generate the correct JSON serialization of a value.  You should also set the content type of the response to `application/json`.  Use `app.response_class` to build a response.

```
from flask import json

return app.response_class(json.dumps(True), content_type='application/json')
```

Typically, you would send more than a single value as the response.  Flask provides `jsonify` as a shortcut to return a JSON object with the keys and values you pass it.  (It's been improved in Flask dev version to handle other data besides objects.)

```
from flask import jsonify

return jsonify(result=True, id=id)
```